# Does golang provide htonl/htons?

Tags: network-programming, go

In C programming, when I want to send an integer across network, we need to use htonl() or htons() to convert the integer from host byte order
to network byte order before sending it.

But in golang, I have checked the net package, and can't find the similar functions like htons/htonl. So how should I send an integer when using golang? Do I need to implement htons/htonl
 myself?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Network byte order is just big endian, so you can use the [`encoding/binary`](http://godoc.org/encoding/binary) package to perform the encoding.

[For example](http://play.golang.org/p/lB2LD5Q1zx):

```
data := make([]byte, 6)
binary.BigEndian.PutUint16(data, 0x1011)
binary.BigEndian.PutUint32(data[2:6], 0x12131415)
```

Alternatively, if you are writing to an `io.Writer`, the `binary.Write()` function from the same package may be more convenient (again, using the `binary.BigEndian` value as the `order` argument).

Comment: Hint: binary.Read() can be used to read data directly from network connection.

Comment: How about running this in a big endian machine? Since that code swaps the bytes, wouldn't it mess it up?

Comment: nvm, looks like it uses shifts, so it works correctly in all platforms.

Comment: Right.  `binary.BigEndian` reads and writes big endian data to `[]byte` slices, no matter which architecture you're running on.  Thinking of it in terms of byte swapping just complicates matters.

Comment: How would you use this in a `socket()` or other syscall that requires a `uint16`? The `binary.BigEndian.PutUint16()` gives bytes in the correct order, but they need to be converted to a `uint16` to be useful. If I use the same `binary.BigEndian` lib, it will just make them back to the host order.

Comment: @deitch: could you be more specific?  You shouldn't need to manually swap port numbers in an address for `syscall.Bind`, for instance.

Comment: Sure @JamesHenstridge. Here is a specific example. You want to open a raw socket listen to all Ethernet packets on Linux. The third argument to `syscall.Socket()` then should be `syscall.ETH_P_ALL`. But that is an `int` per your local endianness. Network requires bigendian. Your system might be big or little. So do you convert it or not? `htons` is supposed to do this with knowledge of local endianness.

Comment: @deitch: the Go syscall package performs byte swapping for you. For instance https://github.com/golang/go/blob/335569b59804f8d14bdb9c7ee2e8b0c2268226ae/src/syscall/syscall_linux.go#L473-L483 shows implicit reordering of the port value of the address. The protocol argument to `socket()` has never required byte swapping, even in C.

Answer (score 4):

I think what you're after is [`ByteOrder` in `encoding/binary`](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/binary/#ByteOrder).

> > A ByteOrder specifies how to convert byte sequences into 16-, 32-, or 64-bit unsigned integers.

Answer (score 0):

Just convert integers between big-endian and little-endian.

```
// NetToHostShort converts a 16-bit integer from network to host byte order, aka "ntohs"
func NetToHostShort(i uint16) uint16 {
    data := make([]byte, 2)
    binary.BigEndian.PutUint16(data, i)
    return binary.LittleEndian.Uint16(data)
}

// NetToHostLong converts a 32-bit integer from network to host byte order, aka "ntohl"
func NetToHostLong(i uint32) uint32 {
    data := make([]byte, 4)
    binary.BigEndian.PutUint32(data, i)
    return binary.LittleEndian.Uint32(data)
}

// HostToNetShort converts a 16-bit integer from host to network byte order, aka "htons"
func HostToNetShort(i uint16) uint16 {
    b := make([]byte, 2)
    binary.LittleEndian.PutUint16(b, i)
    return binary.BigEndian.Uint16(b)
}

// HostToNetLong converts a 32-bit integer from host to network byte order, aka "htonl"
func HostToNetLong(i uint32) uint32 {
    b := make([]byte, 4)
    binary.LittleEndian.PutUint32(b, i)
    return binary.BigEndian.Uint32(b)
}
```